# Can't extract a link connected to `see all` button from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've created a script to log in to linkedin using requests. The script is doing fine.

After logging in, I used this url `https://www.linkedin.com/groups/137920/` to scrape this name `Marketing Intelligence Professionals` from there which you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GojIH.jpg).

The script can parse the name flawlessly. However, what I wish to do now is scrape the link connected to the `See all` button located at the bottom of that very page shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yxg6.jpg).

[Group link](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/137920/) `you gotta log in to access the content`

I've created so far (it can scrape the name shown in the first image):

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin'
post_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login-submit'
target_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/groups/137920/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['session_key'] = 'your email' #put your username here
    payload['session_password'] = 'your password' #put your password here
    r = s.post(post_url,data=payload)
    r = s.get(target_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    items = soup.select_one("code:contains('viewerGroupMembership')").get_text(strip=True)
    print(json.loads(items)['data']['name']['text'])
```

How can I scrape the link connected to `See all` button from there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an internal Rest API which is called when you click on "See All" :

```
GET https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/search/blended
```

The `keywords` query parameter contains the title of the group you have requested initially (the group title in the initial page).

In order to get the group name, you could scrape the html of the initial page, but there is an API which returns the group information when you gives the group ID :

```
GET https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/groups/groups/urn:li:group:GROUP_ID
```

The group id in your case is 137920 which can be extracted from the URL directly

An example :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urlencode

username = 'your username'
password = 'your password'

link = 'https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin'
post_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login-submit'
target_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/groups/137920/'

group_res = re.search('.*/(.*)/$', target_url)
group_id = group_res.group(1)

with requests.Session() as s:
    # login
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['session_key'] = username
    payload['session_password'] = password
    r = s.post(post_url, data = payload)

    # API
    csrf_token = s.cookies.get_dict()["JSESSIONID"].replace("\"","")
    r = s.get(f"https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/groups/groups/urn:li:group:{group_id}",
        headers= {
            "csrf-token": csrf_token
        })
    group_name = r.json()["name"]["text"]
    print(f"searching data for group {group_name}")
    params = {
        "count": 10,
        "keywords": group_name,
        "origin": "SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL",
        "q": "all",
        "start": 0
    }
    r = s.get(f"https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/search/blended?{urlencode(params)}&filters=List(resultType-%3EGROUPS)&queryContext=List(spellCorrectionEnabled-%3Etrue)",
        headers= {
            "csrf-token": csrf_token,
            "Accept": "application/vnd.linkedin.normalized+json+2.1",
            "x-restli-protocol-version": "2.0.0"
        })
    result = r.json()["included"]
    print(result)
    print("list of groupName/link")
    print([
        (t["groupName"], f'https://www.linkedin.com/groups/{t["objectUrn"].split(":")[3]}') 
        for t in result
    ])
```

A few notes :

- those API call require cookie session
- those API call require a specific header for a XSRF token that is the same as JSESSIONID cookie value
- a special media type `application/vnd.linkedin.normalized+json+2.1` is necessary for the search call
- the parenthesis inside the fields `queryContext` and `filters` shouldn't be url encoded otherwise it will not take these params into account

Answer (score 0):

you can try the selenium, click the `See all` button, and scrape the linked connected content:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/xxxx')
driver.find_element_by_name('s_image').click()
```

selenium docs: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: I didn't even tag selenium but still this suggestion came along. I really don't understand how to be more specific with my question. Thanks.